# Magnolia CMS: reference YAML config from JCR config

Tags: configuration, yaml, jcr, magnolia

I have my `page configuration` done via **JCR** configuration.

I have the `component configuration` using **YAML** configuration.

I want to make this component available to the a template configured in the JCR.

---

The **component** config is under: `/project-website-module/src/main/resources/website-module/components/linkList/linkList.yaml`

I tried to reference this in the template's component availability in different ways:

- `website-module:components/linkList/linkList`
- `website-module:components/linkList/linkList.yaml`
- `/website-module/components/linkList/linkList`
- `/website-module/components/linkList/linkList.yaml`
- `src/main/resources/website-module/components/linkList/linkList`
- `src/main/resources/website-module/components/linkList/linkList.yaml`

But no luck, I keep getting the error:

`"Caused by: info.magnolia.config.registry.Registry$NoSuchDefinitionException: <pathToComponentConfiguration>"`

Answer (score 0):

> The component config is under:
>   `/project-website-module/src/main/resources/website-module/dialogs/linkList/linkList.yaml`

... that's the dialog config, where's the component config yaml? 
Path to the component config not to dialog config is the one that you need to use when referring to the component. And that config file needs to be physically at  `src/main/resources/website-module/templates/components/...` and reference is then `website-module:components/...`.

Also if you have specified module descriptor for the module, name in the module descriptor better match the `website-module`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I made a mistake in my question. I have now corrected it & refer to the **component** config's path

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the `YAML` component configuration under (notice the `templates` directory added):

```
/project-website-module/src/main/resources/website-module/templates
```

In my case, move `linkList.yaml` under:

```
/project-website-module/src/main/resources/website-module/templates/components/linkList/linkList.yaml
```

---

Then in the `JCR` config, use the following path:

```
website-module:components/linkList/linkList
```

---

Note: likewise, `YAML` dialog configurations must be under:

```
/project-website-module/src/main/resources/website-module/dialogs
```